# How to create a drop down Menu that drops smoothly

Tags: java

I am developing a Library System. I was wondering if I could use a drop down menu that will show the options (like register the user, see user details, see book stock) to select using java netbeans. And I need it to be drops smoothly (not like suddenly appearing). When I click on the Menu, it should be drops smoothly and slowly which contains the options like I mentioned above (like register the user, see user details, see book stock).

How can I do that? Please Help

Comment: Which framework do you use for your GUI?

Comment: @pzaenger Are you asking me the Jcomponent I'm using?

Comment: You are using Swing, right?

Comment: @pzaenger : Yes I'm using Swing. Any Help?

Comment: I guess you need to show some code. How do you build your dropdown menu? But do not show all your code, just the relevant stuff.

Comment: Swing is pretty limited when it comes to "fancy" and "smooth" stuff. If you haven't done much UI work in your project yet, you might want to consider doing things in JavaFX right from the start.

Comment: @CrushaK.Rool : Yes I think so, Thanks guys for the Help :)

Comment: I don't wanna be rude. But i would have made a spring webapp... :/

Comment: @Jay : I'm not familiar with it :(

Comment: @Code Bae it's actually simple and interesting. Plus it has many advantages as centralization and platform independance!!! You don't need to Java installed on your device, you only need a web browser. That means you can access your library system from your phone as well!

Comment: can you please help me with that? @Jay

Comment: @CodeBae that is easy. Lets continue this discussion in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127027/code-baes-into-to-java-web)